# Add a remote to a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a GitHub repository, say `https://github.com/mrpandey/proj`.

On my local clone of this repo, I have the following two remotes (both fetch and push):

```
ser    ssh://git@server.com:2222/proj.git
origin https://github.com/mrpandey/proj.git
```

`ser` is the git server of a platform where I deploy this project. To automate the deployment process, I was writing a GitHub Actions workflow. The workflow needs to push to `ser` whenever changes are pushed to `main` branch of GitHub (origin).

The problem is that `ser` is not added as a remote on `origin`. I verified this by running `git remote -v` in the workflow script.

So, how can I add a remote to the GitHub repo?

I tried pushing my local to the origin, but `ser` doesn't show up on origin. GitHub does not provide shell access through ssh, so can't even run `remote add` on origin.

One way is I could run `remote add` in the workflow script itself. However, I would like to know if there is actually a possibility to add another remote to a GitHub repository without the help of GitHub Actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your remotes aren't part of the repository; they're not pushed to github when you push your changes. Remotes need to be configured in each individual working directory.

You would need to configure the remote in your workflow script by running the appropriate `git remote add ...` command:

```
git remote add ser ssh://git@server.com:2222/proj.git
```

Then you could run `git push ser`

Alternately, you can push directly to a git URL. For example, your workflow script could run:

```
git push ssh://git@server.com:2222/proj.git
```

Of course, for this to work, you'll need to have ssh keys configured appropriately.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming that remotes are not a part of git repo.